# Move a object continuously in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner at unity and try to make a game by watching some tutorial. After finishing my game I wanted to add some more functionality which is dropping objects continuously from up to the plane. But after it dropped on the plane it rising up to a certain level and again dropped on the plane. I don't understand what to do.

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class droper : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    
   
    MeshRenderer renderer;
    Rigidbody rigidbody;

    Vector3 pos1;
    Vector3 pos2;
    Vector3 pos3;

    [SerializeField]float timeToWait =2f;
    [SerializeField]float speed =0.005f;
    
    
    void Start()
    {
       renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
       rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
      

        renderer.enabled= false;
        rigidbody.useGravity= false;

        pos1 = transform.position; 
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Time.time > timeToWait)
        {
           renderer.enabled= true;
           rigidbody.useGravity= true;
           pos2 = transform.position;
             Debug.Log(pos1);
            pos3=new Vector3(transform.position.x,pos1.y,transform.position.z);
            if (pos2.y < pos1.y)
            {
            transform.position=Vector3.MoveTowards(pos2,pos3,speed);
            }
        }
  
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKSUM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways

1. You can use rigidbody.velocity along the axis you want to move, you may want to disable gravity depending on what you are trying to achieve
2. Transform.translate is also an option but it has buggy physics so you shouldn't really use it